# How do I fix Link url undefined error in gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to use Gatsby to auto generate pages from the data parsed to it and keep getting an error on the url generation in  The data is good as pages work if I manually type them into browser but in browser the link to the page says "undefined" instead of pulling the slug data string and adding it to the Link to, code below

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../../components/layout'
import Seo from '../../components/seo'

const BlogPage = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout pageTitle="My Blog Posts">
      {
        data.allMdx.nodes.map(node => (
          <article key={node.id}>
            <h2>
              <Link to={`/blog/${node.frontmatter.slug}`}>
                {node.frontmatter.title}
              </Link>
            </h2>
            <p>Posted: {node.frontmatter.date}</p>
          </article>
        ))
      }
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

I've tried restarting localhost etc but no matter what I do

```
<Link to={`/blog/${node.frontmatter.slug}`}>
```

ends up pointing to "localhost:8000/blog/undefined/"

Comment: code looks fine. May be slug is missing in data.

Comment: initially my .mdx files were named 1.mdx, 2.mdx etc with the frontmatter.slug with a different string. By changing the file name to match the slug string it now works. Should the slug and filename always match?